# Why am I getting an error in my web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, web-config, profiles

I have the following section added to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
 <caching>
  <profiles>
   <add extension=".html" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
   <add extension=".htm" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
  <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
   <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
   <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
    <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" location="Client" />
    </profiles>
   </caching>
 </system.webServer>
```

which was taken [directly from here](http://snipplr.com/view/55605/cache-files-in-iis--webconfig/)

but I am getting an error in my web.config, saying:

**Unrecognized configuration section system.web/caching/profiles**

also, I see this in visual studio: [image]

**The element caching has invalid child element 'profiles', List of possible expected: cache, outputcache, outputcacheSettings, sqlCacheDependency'**

did something about this configuration change as I see alot of examples on the web with this exact configuration?

Comment: In the link that you provided, section is inside a <location path="MyWebsite"> I wonder if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot you have the caching under `<system.web>` and not `<system.webServer>` and since profiles is not a valid element under `<caching>` for `<system.web>` you will get that error.

Answer (score 1):

What you show in code example is under `<system.webServer>`, what you show in your screenshot is under `<system.web>`, it needs to be under **webServer** for it to get the profiles option, under system.web like you had it offers all those options that the error you received was talking about, behaves differently depending on where you call it from